# How to fix the size of the figure in the changing range in colorbar scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

When changing the values on the z axis (colorbar), the entire final image has jitter (for example, it shifts due to the multiplying array by -1). Is it possible to fix the size of the entire image? I need somehow to save many figures with different z scales on the colorbar in a fixed size, without any jitter.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array1=np.ones(shape=(50,50))
array2=-np.ones(shape=(50,50))
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
ax = fig1.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap',
                                                ['white','xkcd:bright orange','xkcd:chestnut'],
                                                256)
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=12)

im=plt.imshow(array1,aspect='equal',cmap = cmap)
cax = fig1.add_axes([ax.get_position().x1+0.01,ax.get_position().y0,0.02,ax.get_position().height])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, shrink=2)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
ax1 = fig2.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap',
                                                ['white','xkcd:bright orange','xkcd:chestnut'],
                                                256)
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=12)

im=plt.imshow(array2,aspect='equal',cmap = cmap)
cax1 = fig2.add_axes([ax1.get_position().x1+0.01,ax1.get_position().y0,0.02,ax1.get_position().height])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax1, shrink=2)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you try and set the x and the y limits of the axes (`ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()`) so that it does not automatically try and detect these.

Comment: The problem is not associated with x and y axis. The problem is about z axis (colorbar). It could vary in my case in a different range, thus I can not control it by setting the exact value. I would like to have a constant frame applied for the saved picture, without changes in image size.

Comment: I see, then you show pass in the arguments `vmax` and `vmin` to the `imshow` call, and set these to the desired values, so that they don't change between different plots

Comment: Yes, it works, but only if you know the range "a priori". For example, if you need to set autoscale for each image it will give the discribed problem.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem, are you talking about the jitter of the ticks on the colorbar when you change the vertical scale? Otherwise simply giving the vmax as the max of all arrays and vmin the min of all arrays should work

Comment: Yes, you are right in this case. But I don't know vmax and vmin, they will be calculated only in process of my experiment. And I need autoscale regime. Thus, for example, first data is in range from 0 to 1, and second will be from -10 to 10. This leads to the jitter in image size.